# What do you use as WPF alternative for Win32 Delphi?

Tags: wpf, delphi, user-interface, graphics

If you are sticking with Delphi for Win32, what do you use as GUI framework, in order to approach the versatility and performance of the WPF framework on .NET?

There are some alternatives out there, such as DXScene, but it appears to have a problem with font clarity. Graphics32 and AGG are excellent low-level libraries, but lack a high-level design environment or IDE-plugin.

What do you use to implement a modern vector-based GUI?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be any third party solution for general vector-based UIs on Windows [1], it will have to come from MS, and will have to be supported by other vendors. Since MS won't do that for native code it looks like you're out of luck. [1]: And IMHO this is a good thing, for user interface consistency at least.

Comment: So, freedom of UI design to .NET developers, but better maintain old user interface consistency for native coders? Okay.

Comment: @Domus: I didn't say the situation was good. But you have to realize that MS isn't really caring for "native" development any more. There are ever more APIs that are not or only with difficulties accessible from native apps, and WPF seems to be one of them.

Comment: Have you considered a blend of win32 an wpf? It is possible to mix in some wpf in a win32 application. Take a look at tms interop-component (http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/xv.asp) or even more flexible, RemObjects Hydra (http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx).

Comment: @Vegar: No, on one hand I don't want to ditch Delphi's advantage of being able to deploy a single exe, without too many dependency on external libraries, although .NET is pretty much common stuff right now. On the other, I'm looking for an alternative to WPF, really.

Comment: @mghie - this is complete nonesense. Microsoft said they they believed managed code would become more dominant, but the reality is quite the reverse.

To quote from: ttp://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/11/18/new-windows-api-code-pack-version.aspx

Windows 7 offers new features like the taskbar, libraries, and the Sensor and Location platform, to name a few. ... All these great features are exposed via the Win32 native API. Currently there is no easy way to use these features from managed code applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last year, I would have answered about [DXScene](http://www.ksdev.com) - see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340036/is-dxscene-the-wpf-for-delphi-anyone-used-it).

But now, [wait some weeks, and try FireMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931025/has-anyone-heard-of-firemonkey-inside-the-new-delphi-rad-studio-xe2), which is DXScene bought and integrated into XE2 by Embarcadero!

Just one huge point: WPF is Windows only, whereas FireMonkey is cross-platform - it will run under Mac OS X and even iOS. And in the next XE3 version, it should also be able to create desktop Linux application (just as DXScene did). It uses Direct X under Windows, and Open GL on other platforms (even iOS).

It's not VCL-based not "native control" based, but draws its own vectorial controls using a "all-is-container" modular approach. Thanks to an internal "theming" engine, it is able to render controls as native under Windows or Mac OS X. It won't use a XAML language, both some controls on standard IDE forms, or runtime-created controls, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The Delphi VCL still works just fine for me, and without WPF's infamous "learning cliff".

Comment: The Delphi VCL doesn't offer any vector-based GUI development -- and not integrated in the IDE. I'm not advocating WPF, just looking for an alternative on Win32.

Comment: This is completely informal and not representing anything official in any way, but during CodeRage I had a conversation with David I and among other things, we discussed the possibility of an OpenGL-based vector-graphics visual control system, in conjunction with cross-platform plans for Delphi.  So, what does that mean?  Absolutely nothing, except that David I is thinking about the idea, and we might maybe see something like that in a few years.

Answer (score 0):

I use VCL and DevExpress for all my GUI needs. DevExpress also have a [Skin Library](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExSkins/) if you need a more fancy UI.

Comment: No, no controls. Just a vector-based GUI.

Comment: If I may ask why do you insist on vector-based UI? What's the gain? Just curious.

Comment: Scaling, rotation, complex figure rendering. Basically, all controls that are commonly used today were introduced over twenty years ago. The gain is an improved interaction experience, with "controls" tailored to the task and around the user's mental model. Total freedom of design. Etc.

Comment: Well that's a good enough reason. I'm happy with Delphi's offerings. But if you follow the saying "Choosing the right tool for the job" than maybe Adobe AIR would be the best choice for the job. Net adds to much overhead when compared to AIR.

Comment: Thanks, Mihaela. Do you have any experience with Adobe AIR?

Comment: Not much, I just played with it. But there's a big pile of questions and answers here on that subject. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are no libs which will allow you to use WFP directly in Delphi.

I would suggest you to try and use AGG and build your own lib for such tasks or use AGG's commercial descendant.

Comment: Well, I don't want to use WPF. I'm looking for an alternative library with IDE-plugin. AGG is a 3D library?

Comment: No AGG is a 2D Library with sub-pixel facility.

http://www.aggpas.org/

AGG (and AggPas too) doesn't depend on any graphic API or technology. Basically, you can think of AGG as of a rendering engine that produces pixel images in memory from some vectorial data. But of course, AGG can do much more than that.

Answer (score -5):

Sorry Domus, but WPF is not known as a "performance" framework also isn't hardware accelerated. WPF is a layer over windows 3.1 common controls.

In the other hand Direct2d is hardware-accelerated 2-D graphics API that provides high performance and high-quality rendering for 2-D geometry, bitmaps, and text. And is available in Delphi 2010.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861344.aspx

Comment: Pardon? WPF is layered on top of Direct 3D. Windows 3.1 common controls?!!

Comment: WPF is a new code base that makes heavy use of the graphics card. Maybe you're mixing up WPF with Windows Forms, which is just a layer on top of Windows?!

Comment: Direct2D uses an immediate-mode calling pattern (like Direct3D).
WPF is a managed code framework which uses a retained-mode calling pattern. Please look at your processor usage while running an WPF application.

Comment: @Francis, I'm not sure what the author of this reply meant when he wrote it, but WPF 4 will use Direct2D.

Comment: @Pavel WPF will not use Direct2D directly, it will use its own internal retained-mode API (MIL). This impact directly in performance and memory usage compared with C++ or any native code talking directly to direct2d