# Is DxScene the "WPF for Delphi"? Anyone used it?

Tags: wpf, delphi, user-interface, vector, vector-graphics

I am playing with DxScene and VxScene:
http://www.ksdev.com/dxscene/index.html

It looks very nice and powerful: 3d accelerated vector graphics, cross plaform, nice effects, many 2d GUI controls (vector based), good scaling, transparency, rotating (x, y, z), 3d models, etc. Even with many effects, the CPU stays very low (0%)!
http://www.ksdev.com/dxscene/snapshot/screen0.jpeg

But can it be seen as a good WPF alternative for Delphi?

And does anyone use it instead of normal Delphi VCL?

Comment: Who put "seems the same as this" there? Seems like that should have been a comment.

Comment: You're right, @Domus. As for who put it there, you can easily discover that by looking at the question's edit history, available through the "edited X ago" link to the left of the author box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I am using it now in a new project and intend to use it for all future projects.

It's indeed extremely powerful and versatile. It does consume SVG and even XAML, among many other formats, so you could consider it as a Win32 API WPF alternative. Believe me, I've been looking for one for ages, and this is it for me.

Current drawback: lack of documentation. You have to learn it all from the examples and by asking questions in their forum. Not ideal, but it can only get better!

All it needs is more users, and it'll grow into something wonderful.

Comment: Where or how can I import (consume) a .XAML file with DxScene?

Comment: @André: the TvxPath component has a data property. You can paste SVG or XAML data in there.

Comment: I found something in the online help:
http://www.ksdev.com/vgscene/help/path.html

But that's only for paths (WPF Mesh?), not "any" WPF XAML file...

I tried the following example:
http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=50

But I had to strip the XAML tag till I had this:
M 100,100 C 100,200 400,300 400,400
M 600,100 C 600,200 500,300 500,400
M 100,100 L 600,100
M 400,400 L 500,400

Comment: I have only experimented with SVG paths at the moment, since I use InkScape, and only read about the XAML in the (very sparse) documentation. It is very likely that he only implemented the basic vector drawing parts of XAML, but you'd have to ask him directly or in the forum on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it looks like it's the GUI base for [FlStudio](http://flstudio.image-line.com/)

Comment: If not Graphics32 then their own engine.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this article interesting, it explains how to use the DirectWrite and Direct2D features in Delphi 2010, it seems to be rather simple, and is well explained here: [Delphi 2010 DirectWrite "Hello World" Example [1]](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/pawelglowacki/2009/12/14/38872).

[image: Hello World Example using DirectWrite]
*Screenshot from the article showing the result.*

[1] http://blogs.embarcadero.com/pawelglowacki/2009/12/14/38872

Comment: Yes, I know that article, but VCL does not default use that, and Direct2D only works with Windows 7.

Btw, VxScene also uses Direct2D now:
http://ksdev.blogspot.com/2010/03/direct2d-directwrite-preview.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks very promising, the effects are very good, in the past years I have seen it's being enhanced constantly. I have check it the second time today (only the compiled demo), it seems that many new controls are added, I like the "expander" expandable panel.

It's very promising, I'm consider using it in the future, I'm not sure if the new version has fix or not, but when the first time I checked the trial version, it lacks of documentation...

Very good effect and promising though!